# Lat Long in Windows mobile 6 application

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-gps

i am very new to windows mobile programming , I want to know how to fetch lat long or the GPS details on the phone. Please suggest me some example or the way to do it.also suggect me some good book i can refer to start the programming from the scratch on windows mobile.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Mobile SDK ships with a working GPS sample. On my PC it's located at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CS\GPS\GpsSample